# Android Studio's emulator camera opening upside down?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm running a Nexus 5, API 23, and opening the camera with:

```
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

However once this opens the camera appears upside down by default like this:

[image: Upside down camera example]

I've checked other threads which say to disable 'Use Host GPU' and to set the activity's screenOrientation to sensorPortrait but these haven't worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the Android Emulator, press the 3 dots (`...`). Then click on `Virtual Sensors`.

When in the menu, there are 4 presets. You want to press the first one, which is upright. You may also have to use the other (upside down) one.

[image: Virtual Sensors Menu]

Comment: I don't use Android Studio anymore so if anyone can confirm this works I'll mark this as the solution

Comment: I had the same issue and had it working for a few minutes with the upright position, it works for me but sometimes you have to use the "upside-down" preset. Either this or that will 100% work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the hard way :

- There is a button in the side bar. Try using that
- CTRL + F11
- Mac : CMD + F11

Comment: That's not doing anything for me unfortunately @Android4Fun

Comment: what happens if you just open the camera from default camera app?

Comment: Also upside down

Comment: I'm in the same boat with same setup. Did you ever wind up figuring this out?

Comment: @chell No I never figured this out. It was for a university project where everyone experienced the same issue and nobody managed to resolve it, sorry!

Comment: No worries, thanks for replying! I've given up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with the camera being upside down for all apps, which strangely was fixed when I went into the emulator settings and unchecked "enable keyboard input"